# ASP.NET Session Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Hey Just wondering how the following can happen

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()

```
    If (Session("userId") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("site_base_url").ToString & "login/", False)
    End If

    customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()
```

Now I currently have no session set on this page. So the session is NULL but i am just wondering why my if statement is taking care of this problem, why does it even try to get to the next part i.e. Response.Write ?

Comment: Apparently, your `userName` session variable is null. It should crash when you initially attempt to assign `userName` to your text field. Is this where the behavior is occuring?  You stated in your question, there are no session variables set at this point.

Comment: Are you sure that the Session object is null? Test your assumption.

Comment: Hey George, this is the thing that has been driving me crazy all days and simply cant understand. In the above script all my session variables are null and I know this. But as far as I can see the code goes into the  if statement and because session is null hence Session("userId") Is Nothing is true, it should redirect to login. Why oh why, does it go beyond that attempt to attach the session "username" to the literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet it looks like the line `Response.Write(Session("UID").ToString)` will **always** be executed regardless of what happens with the `if` statement above it.

I wonder if the weird indentation isn't confusing you. Try looking at it like this:

```
If (Session("userName") IsNot Nothing) Then
    customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()
End If

Response.Write(Session("UID").ToString)
```

Notice that I aligned the `End If` with the corresponding `If` above and the `Response.Write...` as well. The `Response.Write...` line clearly sits outside of the `If` block and since there is not return or break or continue in the `If` block it will always get executed.

And btw, it's probably not the `Session` object that is null. You are calling `ToString` on an item you assume to be contained in the Session object. It's more likely that the Session does not contain a "UID" entry.

Comment: Sorry see my edit, I posted the wrong code. I meant the shouldnt the redirect take care of the empty session why does it go beyond and attempt to load Session("userName")

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Write()` is outside of the `IF` statement, so whether or not the Session `Is Nothing`, the `Response.Write()` method will be ran.

---

Alternatively, perhaps youre trying to assign a value to the Session if it doesnt already have one? In this case, I think you have your code in reverse:

```
customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString()
```

Should be:

```
Session("userName") = customerName.Text
```

Comment: Sorry see my edit, I posted the wrong code. I meant the shouldnt the redirect take care of the empty session why does it go beyond and attempt to load Session("userName")

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString();
```

will be executed no matter what the value of the session is. In the if condition, you are checking for the **(Session("userId")** and not **Session("userName")**. Both of them are different session variables. If for some reason **Session("userName")** value is not assigned prior, you will get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.
I would do a session null check first before assigning the value to customerName.Text

```
if(Session("userName") IsNot Nothing) Then
    customerName.Text = Session("userName").ToString();
```

Comment: Vinay, thanks for replying. And yes I understand what you are saying. But lets say I have 10 User Session variables I dont want to go i.e. if(Session("userName") IsNot Nothing and if(Session("email") IsNot Nothing and if(Session("userId") IsNot Nothing etc.... I just thought If I check 1 of the session variables i.e. a strong one like userId I could simply check for this one to null no ?

Comment: Stevie, This might sound silly, but are you sure the session(userId) is null? I suppose the session("userId") is getting assigned some value somewhere. I would try the same thing with Session("UserName") and see if it is behaving the same way as session("userId").